# Approximating a curve with arctan

Tags: r

I have a set of data points which look a lot like some version of arctan(x).

```
xs <- seq(1000,50000,by=1000)

data <- c(0.101, 0.169, 0.209, 0.256, 0.289, 0.373, 0.391, 0.418, 0.477, 0.528, 0.579, 0.570, 0.602, 0.657, 0.690, 0.720, 0.747, 0.764, 0.781, 0.811, 0.842, 0.847, 0.864, 0.889, 0.871, 0.894, 0.897, 0.915, 0.926, 0.931, 0.932, 0.940, 0.950, 0.963, 0.956, 0.967, 0.967, 0.963, 0.971, 0.980, 0.986, 0.988, 0.986, 0.985, 0.993, 0.992, 0.994, 0.991, 0.995, 0.993)

plot(xs,data)
```

After fiddling around a little in sage I came up with the curve `y = 2*atan(xs/1000)/pi`

However the 1000 here is only a guess.

The approximation turns out to be reasonable

```
model <- lm(data ~ I(2*atan(xs/10000)/pi))

points(xs,model$fitted.values, pch=20)
```

My question is, how can I get R to "guess" the value a in the curve `y = 2*atan(x/a)/pi` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a loss function (in the code below, mean squared error), and get `optim` to minimize the loss:

```
form <- function(a, xs) 2 * atan(xs / a) / pi
loss <- function(a, xs, data) mean((form(a, xs) - data)^2)
optimized <- optim(1000, loss, xs = xs, data = data, method = "Brent", lower = 1, upper = 10000)
a <- optimized$par
a
# [1] 7069.42
```